# Greedy Alg: Occupying Start time to Finish time

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, shortest-path, greedy

**Background info:**

Given a list of proposed  : A = {a1, a2, …, ax} where each assignment runs from a specified start time to a specified finish time, select a minimum size set of assignments so that all times from a given S to F are occupied with at least one assignment.

Assignments may overlap and may start before the start time and end after the finish time.

Only requirement: No gaps between selected assignments

All information is given in assignments.txt file in the following format:

```
2   8      // the first line gives the start time and end time
5          // the second line gives the number of assignments to choose from
1   1   3  // the subsequent lines give the assignment number, start time, and finish time
2   2   6
3   5   7
4   6   9
5   5   10
```

How would one go about coding for this algorithm in python?

My idea:
Read the text file and store into an array. Separate elements of the array according to their respective properties, and then go about coding for the greedy alg i.e. pick longest assignments consecutively while abiding within the start and finish time.

This is what I have so far:

```
def readFile():
file = open( "assignments.txt", "r" )
unsortedArray = []
for line in file:
    toInt = map(int,line.split())
    unsortedArray.append(toInt)
print unsortedArray
return unsortedArray

def sortArray(unsortedArray):
    for i in range(2, len(unsortedArray)):
        if unsortedArray[i][1] > unsortedArray[i+1][1]:
             unsortedArray[i],unsortedArray[i+1] = unsortedArray[i+1],unsortedArray[i]
        print unsortedArray[i]

def main():
    readFile()
    sortArray(readFile())

main()
```

Comment: "...and may start before the start time and end after the finish time". If this is true, then you can just greedily pick the largest set of jobs that fill the required interval and run them consecutively. The actual starting and ending times are irrelevant; only the difference between the two matters.

Comment: @chepner That is a great point, but 'm having trouble coding it all in java.

Comment: If this is about Java, please remove the Python tag. If the language is unimportant, remove both tags. You could also use the "language-agnostic" tag if you think it's necessary..

Comment: @m69 my apologies. Editing as necessary